# Link sks file to swift class

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am unable to link a `sks` file with a `swift` class.

I have a `sks` named `GameScene.sks` and swift file named `GameScene.swift`

Custom class for sks file is set to `GameScene`[image]

Contents of `GameScene.swift` are -

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("here")
    }
}
```

The print statement is not executed. The `didMove` method never executes.

Comment: what is your iOS target version?

Comment: target version is 10.0

Comment: how do you load the sks file?  `if let scene = SKScene("Gamescene.swift")?`

Comment: `if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` in `GameViewController`

Comment: ok, then goto where you set the Custom Class name, change it, hit ENTER, then change it to GameScene, hit ENTER, then hit CMD + S

Comment: Nothing. Have done that multiple times.

Comment: then either you are not presenting `scene`, or you are not using target 10.0, could you show the entire chunk of your view controller code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140002/discussion-between-utkbansal-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: I agree with @Knight0fDragon 90% of my .sks errors are fixed by hitting enter on the field and then hitting cmd+s....very frustrating

Comment: Just copied both the files to a new project. And guess what? It worked without changing anything. :|

Comment: @utkbansal. Thanks for that comment! I had the same issue when starting up a clean SpriteKit project in Xcode 8.3.3. I managed to fix it by choosing a  project name without a dash in the name. Maybe we stumbled upon bug here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below piece of code.

```
    let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: You should not be doing it this way, the idea is to make it swap-able, so if you want to load in a different scene, there is no need to use a switch statement to load the correct class